# Does the event loop run on same thread as the JS main thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, event-loop

I am trying to understand asynchronous JavaScript but one thing that I'm wondering is, does the event loop run on the main thread? If so, does all  synchronous code in `Main()` have to go through the event loop? (E.g. does `console.log("Hello")` also have to go through the event loop?)
And is the event loop the only one who is allowed to push functions to call stack?

Comment: One thing that I think you are confused about is you think that the event loop somehow runs code in parallel with the code in your `main()` (in javascript this is just synchronous code in the script you run). It does not. `main()` calls the event loop at the end of itself. So all synchronous code in `main()` runs before the event loop. If you have any code that causes `main()` to not reach the end (for example `while (1) {}` then the event loop never runs (this means everything controlled by the event loop never happens: no network I/O, no browser update etc.)

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, the event loop runs on the same thread as your main function.
2. No, the event loop doesn't start processing messages until your main function returns.  `console.log()` is synchronous (although there may be some asynchronous processes involved in generating the console output, they have nothing to do with the event loop).

There is only one way that a function (or more accurately a function's stack frame) gets onto the call stack -- the function gets called by whatever is currently on the top of the stack.  A function gets removed from the call stack when it returns or throws.  In a thread, the function at the top of the stack is what's currently running.

The event loop is at the bottom of the stack, or at least it's underneath all JavaScript functions, so it only gets to run when all previously running JavaScript functions have returned or thrown.

Comment: Thanks  Brother  You Clear my  doubt  but  one  more question  who  pushes  eventloop and  main  function  to  call stack is  it  JS Engine??

Comment: Essentially, yes.  There's no rule about it, but it's all just code.  There's an internal function in the JS Engine that calls main and then executes the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the event loop run on same thread as the JS main thread?

JavaScript is often called single threaded, because different pieces of JavaScript can't run at the same time. (Although with the introduction of [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), this isn't necessarily true anymore.) Whether you call this the "main" thread depends on your definition of "main". If you are asking about whether the event loop itself runs on the same thread as the messages it executes, than that would make sense, but this is implementation dependent.

JavaScript doesn't dictate any threading at all. It makes sense for implementations to use only a one thread for the event loop and the JavaScript execution because all the code will always run sequentially, but this isn't a requirement.

As for your questions about event loop and the call stack, you first need to understand how those two work.

The event loop is a simple mechanism that executes queued messages in order and if none are available, it will wait until a new one comes in. A message can be anything that isn't executed immediately. Such as (but not limited to) incoming events (such as clicks), responses from AJAX calls or a callback from `setTimeout()`.

The call stack is the stack of function calls. When a function is invoked (directly, so not via the event loop), a new frame is added to the stack that will be executed. Once the function has completed, the frame is removed from the stack and the code of the previous frame will continue from the point it invoked the completed function. Once all functions are complete and the call stack is empty, the event loop will run the next message.

So to answer your remaining questions:

> does all synchronous code in `Main()` have to go through the event loop?

Not directly. The event loop only invokes the message and wait for it to complete. It doesn't interfere with the execution of the message itself.

> is the event loop the only one who is allowed to push functions to call stack?

The only time the event loop interacts with the call stack (or the "execution context stack" as the specification calls it), is when it "[spins the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop)". In such a case, the call stack is copied for later use, some other task is performed and later the copied call stack is restored so the execution can continue from the point it left off. But this only happens on a handful of occasions.

Generally, frames are added to the call stack when a (synchronous) function is called. The event loop has little to do with that.

---

You can read more about the event loop [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Comment: Almost correct, the last part is a bit deceptive. Actually the event loop (at least in a browser) can manage the call stack too, it may decide to "pause" a long running task (e.g one responsible to execute js code), and to resume it later on so it can process other more urgent tasks in between (e.g UI rendering) This process is called "spinning the event loop". Doing so, it has to take a snapshot of the call stack to be able to resume the task later. But the most important point that should be made is probably that js execution is just a (small) part of all the tasks the event loop manages.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I highly appreciate the feedback. I've edited my question accordingly. One small remark I came across: The specification distinguishes between spinning the event loop and pausing it. The latter doesn't copy the call stack, but instead pauses the event loop as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Javascript is single threaded,and the event loop doesn't run like code because it is not.

The event loop has one simple job as a mechanism, which is : To monitor the CALL STACK and CALL QUEUE, if the call stack is empty, the EVENT LOOP takes the first event from the QUEUE and will push it to the CALL STACK, which effectively runs it.

I hope this makes you see the EVENT LOOP from a different perspective.

Comment: Bro  can you explain this statement " he event loop doesn't run like code because it is not" please  :)

Comment: I mean, see the event loop as an engine not as a code